# Kubuntu is unable to start GUI(Xorg)

Tags: boot, kubuntu, xorg, gui

I am not very experienced with Linux so I apologize if the description of my problem is in some way lacking.
So, for some unknown reason, my Kubuntu installation sometimes breaks down and does not want to boot into GUI. Everything goes fine, both BIOS and GNU grub works, and then after selecting Kubuntu, it gets stuck at the motherboard manufacturer logo. Because it does not go any further, no matter how long I wait (30 min+, whole boot process normally takes around 1min on my computer), I decided to switch to CLI mode, in order to see if it will work. I log in with no problem, everything seems to work just fine, so I try to start GUI manually with startx, but then it displays a message taking up the whole screen stating that it encountered a problem (no more details about the problem, just error message) and I need to log off. I click the log-off button in the message, and then it takes me back to CLI, but it gets broken(lines are offset, commands do not show up when I write them, only the results of commands being executed). It happened to me two times, at first, I thought that I screw something up while I was installing the driver to my graphics card. After that, I got into advanced boot options, and booted up different Kubuntu versions (different kernel version,  5.8 instead of 5.13). I decided that I would keep using this working version until I figure out what I screwed up with the previous one. Then, around a month later, the exact same problem happened to the second version. I did not tinker with this version in any way, I was using default drivers, did not install anything weird, or change any system files. Again, I got exactly the same results. I have no idea what is wrong, let alone how to fix it, so I ask for some ways to figure out what the problem is. 
This is my hardware:

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3100 4-Core Processor
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
SSD: Patriot P300 1TB
Memory: 16GB RAM
```

Software:

```
Kubuntu 21.4
Xorg: 1.20.11
```

Edit: I added pictures of error messages
[First error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXGJW.jpg)

[this is what shows up after I click Log out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocKmX.jpg)
Edit 2: 
[link to my Xorg log file](https://pastebin.pl/view/6eed8993)

Comment: "*no more details about the problem, just error message*" - that's exactly what errors are.  Same with the output of commands you are running. You should include this information in your question: it is essential diagnostic info a lot more valuable than any narrative description.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for the suggestion, I've added pictures to my original suggestion, but I do not think they are going to change much. By "no more details about the problem, just error message" I meant no error code, no info about what is going on in the slightest, the only message that "Something has gone wrong" and then after doing exactly what the message said, there is no more info to be seen.

Comment: The warning says to make sure you have the latest version of software and you have at least 59 updates available. You should reboot into recovery to get a root shell prompt with networking.  Then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Then reboot again. We can at least get your basic system maintenance caught up and if it doesn't solve the problem we can check that off the list

Comment: @Nmath I have updated everything, and nothing changed.

Comment: "*at first, I thought that I screw something up while I was installing the driver to my graphics card*" - you should edit your question and include clear, reproducible details about this and any other steps you've taken preceding and since the problems began. Be specific, clear, exact, and unambiguous.  Don't leave out details that might help us understand the problem

Comment: @Nmatch I do not remember all of this exactly, but for some reason, the default driver did not want to work with any steam games. There was no problem with other programs (blender for example was using my GPU just fine, and programs games that could be run both through steam and without it could use GPU only if not launched through steam.)

Comment: Because I could not find any way to fix this issue with steam, and my driver version was not the newest, I tried to update the driver. At first, I have tried doing this through apt, but because of my lack of experience I did something wrong, and no programs could use GPU then, and I had some broken driver packages. Because I have installed a new driver manually, the option to switch back was not there.

Comment: Then, I tried to install it by rung the Nvidia installation script,  but it could not proceed because some modules of the driver installed previously were loaded (it seems that some parts of the driver had installed correctly, and some did not). The part that was loaded was responsible necessary to display any part of the GUI to screen, so after I googled it, I have found out that I need to go to CLI mode, unload this kernel module, and then run the installation script.

Comment: Everything seemed to run perfectly, after installation I had no problems with my GPU whatsoever, programs run with no problem. Around two weeks after that, I have experienced the error I have described in the post. After the error, I switched to a different Kubuntu version in GNU grub, and all things seemed to run fine.
I did not change anything this time, and the error still hapened.

Comment: Thinking about this, I have recalled one more detali about first time this error hapened: one boot before my system had problems with booting, one of my games(modded Cities Skylines) had hung up during loading, and it took whole system with it(i have waited over 15 min, no reaction).At this time, i had no idea if there was any other way to solve this than to just power down my PC, and because it did not want to power down after I pressed power off button, I unplugged it(I know this is something jus should not do, but I did not know how to solv this diffrent way).

Comment: Second time this error happened I have powered down my pc normally(through the shut down button in application launcher).I do not recall anything else, and I would like to thank you for spending your time helping me.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of problems, not just one. It might be more prudent to reinstall the OS, especially if you did not keep any explicit documentation from all of the previous errors. Without being able to read the output of those previous errors, it will be difficult to diagnose and fix.  As far as your games and mods, some mods in particular may be designed for a different OS.  I would not fault your GPU driver for this and in fact, doing a lot of manipulation with your drivers may be responsible for some other problems.

Comment: If you choose to reinstall, you should choose to install the proprietary nvidia driver during installation instead of after the fact. Make sure you enable proprietary 3rd party software and download updates during install.  If you encounter any problem after installation, ask a new question and make sure that you recount your exact steps in a way that is reproducible and provide all errors and output verbatim